# React get native element or Height and Width of a child that was passed in props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How in react I can get the native html element or get the boundiers of an element that was pass to as a child in props?

given the next component:

```
class SomeComp extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
       this.props.children.forEach(child => {
           // I need the native element to get the offsetTop and the .getBoundingClientRect() func of html 
       })
    }
    render() {
        <div>
         {this.props.children}
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get access to the `DOM` element using refs.
Please read official documentation about that feature: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @falinsky but i need the ref to the elements in the `props.children` i cant set ref to the children or can i?

Comment: I posted a separate answer, please consider it.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you can read about [Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Then you can try to map your children elements with each with another element and pass there a instance of `ref` via prop. After that you can access particular `DOM` element for wrapper via that ref instance.

See example below (example is valid since `React 16.3`):

*Solution updated to stop adding additional divs as wrappers for children.*

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.refsArray = [];
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.refsArray.forEach(ref => {
      console.log(ref.current.offsetTop);
    })
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        {React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, index) => {
          const ref = React.createRef();
          this.refsArray.push(ref); 

          return React.cloneElement(child, {ref, key: index});
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render((
  <App>
    <div>This</div>
    <div>is</div>
    <div>my</div>
    <div>test</div>
  </App>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Another way to achieve a particular `DOM` element of particular mounted component is via `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component)` (see [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode)). But this approach is not recommended in favor of using `refs` feature.

Comment: You solution works. but it added a `div` for every child and this can change the sizes of the elements. i posted a solution that works without this

Answer (score -1):

This is the best solution i found that gives exactly what i wanted

just map over the children and return a clone of the element with additional ref

```
this.props.children.map((element, index) => (
    <element.type {...element.props} ref={r => do what ever with ref} key={index}> {element.props.children} </element.type>
)
```

Comment: you should not use `.map()` with `this.props.children` as it is not always an array. please see more about `React.Children` - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren

Comment: I updated solution to stop creating divs around children. I suggest you to use `React.cloneElement()` instead of your proposed one.